# custom allocator for std::unordered_map to set a incremental value

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have a type below:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
```

the `int` field is the index for the string, which will be used by others. Now if someone queries this map in this way: `int id = map["foo"]`, and if the `foo` is not in the map, then I want the map to add a new key as `foo` **and set it's value to** `map.size()`(let's say no element will be deleted, so just using map.size() as the new index would be acceptable).

So can I do this? (e.g. set allocator as template parameter)

Or is there any better data structure to do this? (I considered set or unordered set, but getting index from a set seems too complicated)

Comment: Why not insert `"foo"` manually with the required index if it is not present in the `map`?

Comment: @CinCout because if that, the caller will determine whether the element is in the map, I just want others get easier.

Answer (score 3):

> So can I do this?(e.g. set alloctor as template parameter)

Not really. You can set an allocator, but an allocator's purpose is to hand out memory whenever the container requests it. You can't portably provide an allocator that will do what you want, because you can't predict how exactly a container will use your allocator across standard library implementations.

What you wish to do is also a hack. Allocators should be provided only to manage custom memory resources, and they should not expect to do much more beyond adhering to the standard's allocator requirements.

As it were, if all wish to do is provide something that is *mostly* a `std::unordered_map` but with a tweak to `operator[]`, then the path to it is fairly easy:

```
template<typename K, typename V, typename... OtherArgs>
struct my_uomap : std::unordered_map<K, V, OtherArgs...> {
    using my_uomap::unordered_map::unordered_map; // Inherit the c'tors
    V& operator[](K const& k) {
       // Do something custom
    }
    // And the other overload too
};
```

Don't let naysayers frighten you about inheriting from a standard library container. This is an issue only when you delete objects polymorphically. That is rarely how standard containers are used, even though you should keep that in mind.

Comment: As an extra precaution for the "non-polymorphic deletion" case, I ususally declare `operator new (size_t) = delete` in classes such as this, to lessen the risk.

Comment: As an alternative solution, in the case you want to rely on composition instead of inheritance, you can create a class `A` (purposefully equivalent to the `my_uomap` of this answer) that owns a non-static `std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t>` and makes it available through a getter. If your use of the `std::unordered_map` is very specific, then `A` becomes the perfect place to maintain the functions that are specific to your application (in which case you can probably get rid of the getter).